# How to awake the Wifi or 3G of an Android device by app?

Tags: android, wifi, state

I'm developing a server websocket based application for Android but usually doesn't works correctly. When it fails and I try to ping the device from my PC, I can't access it. I must reset the device or turn On the flight mode and turn it off again. Then, I can reach the device with a ping command and my server works well.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Edited:
I found the solution here:
http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/27/how-to-prevent-wi-fi-sleep-on-android/

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WifiLock;


WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiLock lock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "LockTag");
lock.acquire();
```

Edited again...

Nop, I thaught that it will work but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You may want the application to ensure that Wifi is enabled on the device.  You cannot enable it programmatically but you can open the wireless settings menu so the user can enable it.  To detect if there is a network connection you can use the following code:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager  
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

if(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // There is a connection
    ...
}
else {
    // No connection; open the wireless settings menu
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
    ...
}
```

You will also need the following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I will try checking the connectivity with your solution, but I suspect that probably 'activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())' will return true and the powersaving feature will still on. I will tell you tomorrow the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/pepedeab/libGDX-Net/blob/master/servidor/src/com/jlcm/servidor/WSServer.java . Sometimes the server doesn't respond correclty (doesn't turn on or awake the Wifi). In the method startServer is defined the Websocket.

Comment: I found the solution here:http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/27/how-to-prevent-wi-fi-sleep-on-android/